# Why is is-operator not functioning like ==?

Tags: python

If I understand correctly, the is operator can take the place of ==.

Why when I write

```
if inpty == "exit":
    return
```

does the function exit, but when I write

```
if inpty is "exit":
    return
```

the function does not?

inpty is the value of the input.

Comment: Has been asked and explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is` compares *identity*, whereas `==` compares *equality*.
In other words, `a is b` is the same as `id(a) == id(b)`.

Comment: So the is operator checks the memory address?

Comment: @eidlyn: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

because in this case, the `is` operator is testing identity, not the value.

Comment: the question was why does is not evaluate to true? and that is because it is testing identity not value?